# Neo4j is not running after putting the right path

Tags: neo4j

his isn't working after I press the confirm button. I installed Java JDK and set the correct path in the environment variables, but it keeps showing this error repeatedly. I've tried my best to resolve this issue, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to fix it. I'm attempting to provide the path for Neo4j, but unfortunately, it's not running after doing so

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you doing when you press the "confirm button"? You have to provide a lot more details. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).